# phoenix server fails after being built with `mix release`

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix, exrm

I have a simple phoenix application, and I tried to deploy it using [`exrm`](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm). The application works fine when I run it using

```
mix phoenix.start
```

But after building it using

```
mix release
```

(which finishes without error), running the executable returns an error:

```
rel/my_app/bin/my_app foreground

Exec: /home/ubuntu/projects/my_app/rel/my_app/erts-6.0/bin/erlexec -noshell -noinput +Bd -boot /home/ubuntu/projects/my_app/rel/my_app/releases/0.0.1/my_app -mode embedded -config /home/ubuntu/projects/my_app/rel/my_app/releases/0.0.1/sys.config -args_file /home/ubuntu/projects/my_app/rel/my_app/releases/0.0.1/vm.args -user Elixir.IEx.CLI -extra --no-halt +iex -- foreground
Root: /home/ubuntu/projects/my_app/rel/my_app
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.0] [source-07b8f44] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,my_app,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.MyApp',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{'Elixir.MyApp',start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},{line,272}]}]}}}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,my_app,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.MyApp',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{'Elixir.MyApp',start,[normal,[]],[]},{application
```

My `mix.exs` look like this:

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [ app: :my_app,
      version: "0.0.1",
      elixir: "~> 0.13.2",
      deps: deps ]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application
  def application do
    [
      mod: { MyApp, [] },
      applications: [:phoenix]
    ]
  end

  # Returns the list of dependencies in the format:
  # { :foobar, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/foobar.git", tag: "0.1" }
  #
  # To specify particular versions, regardless of the tag, do:
  # { :barbat, "~> 0.1", github: "elixir-lang/barbat" }
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "0.2.4"},
      {:jazz, github: "meh/jazz", ref: "7af3b74e58eb1a3fc6b9874a2077efa420f6dfcc"},
      {:cowboy, github: "extend/cowboy", override: true, ref: "05024529679d1d0203b8dcd6e2932cc2a526d370"},
      #{ :redis, "1.1.0", [ github: "timbuchwaldt/elixir-redis"] },
      {:erlcloud,github: "gleber/erlcloud"},
      { :json,  github: "cblage/elixir-json" },
      { :amnesia, github: "uriagassi/amnesia" },
      { :exrm, "~> 0.8.1"}
    ]
  end
end
```

And `my_app.ex` contains `start/2`:

```rb
defmodule MyApp do
  use Application.Behaviour

  # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Application.Behaviour.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  def start(_type, _args) do
    MyApp.Supervisor.start_link
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Elixir?  v0.13.2?  What happens if you try it with a more recent version?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci - `amnesia` does not support 0.14...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I figured out that another file in the project (besides `my_app.ex`) defined `defmodule MyApp`. I'm coming from ruby, and I'm used to having a module used as a package name, and be re-used as needed.

Changing the name of the second module (to `MyApp.Database`) got me past that problem.

The most confusing part is that the application works perfectly when run using

```
mix phoenix.start
```

I've encountered more problems after that, which are out of the scope for this question, and I might bring them up as separate questions.

Comment: Very interesting. I would guess that the reason for that is that in development, it just redefines the `MyApp` module, but the release is running compiled code, and doesn't permit that, which is why it fails (or so I would guess). Were any of the other problems you encountered specific to exrm?

Comment: yes - I needed to add applications to `applications` which are not in my `mix.exs`, such as `:inflex` and `:ex_conf` - I think they should be implicitly added as applications of dependent applications

Comment: Also, I needed to add the router to the supervisor workers because I couldn't use phoenix's `mix phoenix.start` in the binary. It was exceptionally difficult, since the template where the example router worker is shown is wrong (`# worker(MyApp.Router, [])` instead of `worker(MyApp.Router, [], function: :start)`

Comment: @bitwalker - I also had other difficulties running the binary(though this is probably more phoenix related than exrm), since when you don't set the environment, by default it is run in `"dev"` mode, which fails because of code reload, and when you set it to `"prod"`, it fails because there is no `PORT` set in the environment. All of this happens with non-helpful errors, so debugging it is a bitch...

Comment: Applications which are dependencies of dependencies should be added to the dependency's mix.exs, or .app.src in the case of Erlang deps. If they aren't, then the author should be notified, as that is an issue with their application, not with the release process.

Comment: Interesting, the release is built with MIX_ENV=prod, so the release should contain your prod config, and the app will build with any prod specific environment settings. I'll chat with Chris McCord to see if there is anything I can do to building releases for Phoenix apps less of a pain, or at least more clear in terms of requirements.

Comment: @bitwalker - thanks for the attention and care, in case we choose Elixir for the coming project, I'm sure we'll talk again, and I'll be happy to contribute wherever I can.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure all of your deps are in the applications list. The reason the app fails on startup is because it can't find one of your dependencies.

Comment: No joy... added all deps to the applications list (`applications: [:phoenix, :jazz, :cowboy, :erlcloud, :json, :amnesia]`), and I still get the same error...

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation describing the structure of `mix.exs`?

Comment: This is the best I could find, but it's not comprehensive: http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/mix_otp/1.html

Comment: Is the source for this up on GitHub somewhere? I can take a look at what's going wrong here, but it's a bit difficult to troubleshoot without an example app which reproduces the problem. After re-reading through the code you posted, I see nothing wrong with what you have, so something else must be missing from the equation.

Comment: I've managed to get past this problem (see my answer), but I would _love_ to chat with you about the other problems I've encountered, which I believe should be tackled at the framework level (or at least raise the proper errors as soon as possible)...